# Why opengl code in a lib doesn't renderer?

Tags: opengl, rendering, windows, c, glfw

I am experimenting with opengl using c99 on windows and vs 2022 i tried to create an window using glfw in one project and put a function that supposed to generate a texture in another project that is compiled into static library (.lib) and linked to the first project that creates the window when i run the program it crashes put when i copy the code from the func to the first project the texture render probably when debugging the func before the crash the value returned from glGenTextures equal 1 so i think it can't render to the opengl context or i am wrong could any one tell me what is happens or is it normal and is there a work around

Main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <glad/glad.h>
#include <glfw/glfw3.h>

#include <gl2d.h>

void framebuffer_size_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height);
void processInput(GLFWwindow* window);

const char* vertexShaderSource = "#version 330 core\n"
"layout(location = 0) in vec3 aPos;\n"
"layout(location = 1) in vec3 aColor;\n"
"layout(location = 2) in vec2 aTexCoord;\n"
"out vec3 ourColor;\n"
"out vec2 TexCoord;\n"

"void main() {\n"
    "gl_Position = vec4(aPos, 1.0);\n"
    "ourColor = aColor;\n"
    "TexCoord = vec2(aTexCoord.x, aTexCoord.y);\n"
"}";

const char* fragmentShaderSource = "#version 330 core\n"
"out vec4 FragColor;\n"
"in vec3 ourColor;\n"
"in vec2 TexCoord;\n"
"uniform sampler2D texture1;\n"
"void main() {\n"
    "FragColor = texture(texture1, TexCoord);\n"
"}";

// settings
const unsigned int SCR_WIDTH = 800;
const unsigned int SCR_HEIGHT = 600;

int main()
{
    // glfw: initialize and configure
    // ------------------------------
    glfwInit();
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

    // glfw window creation
    // --------------------
    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(SCR_WIDTH, SCR_HEIGHT, "LearnOpenGL", NULL, NULL);
    if (window == NULL)
    {
        printf("Failed to create GLFW window\n");
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback(window, framebuffer_size_callback);

    // glad: load all OpenGL function pointers
    // ---------------------------------------
    if (!gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc)glfwGetProcAddress))
    {
        printf("Failed to initialize GLAD\n");
        return -1;
    }

    // build and compile our shader zprogram
    // ------------------------------------
    uint32_t shaderProgram = 0, vertexShader = 0, fragmentShader = 0;
    vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, &vertexShaderSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(vertexShader);
    // check for shader compile errors
    int success;
    char infoLog[512];
    glGetShaderiv(vertexShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
    if (!success)
    {
        glGetShaderInfoLog(vertexShader, 512, NULL, infoLog);
        printf("ERROR::SHADER::VERTEX::COMPILATION_FAILED: %s\n", infoLog);
    }
    // fragment shader
    fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(fragmentShader, 1, &fragmentShaderSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(fragmentShader);
    // check for shader compile errors
    glGetShaderiv(fragmentShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
    if (!success)
    {
        glGetShaderInfoLog(fragmentShader, 512, NULL, infoLog);
        printf("ERROR::SHADER::FRAGMENT::COMPILATION_FAILED: %s\n", infoLog);
    }
    // link shaders
    shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
    glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);
    // check for linking errors
    glGetProgramiv(shaderProgram, GL_LINK_STATUS, &success);
    if (!success) {
        glGetProgramInfoLog(shaderProgram, 512, NULL, infoLog);
        printf("ERROR::SHADER::PROGRAM::LINKING_FAILED: %s\n", infoLog);
    }
    glDeleteShader(vertexShader);
    glDeleteShader(fragmentShader);

    // set up vertex data (and buffer(s)) and configure vertex attributes
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------
    float vertices[] = {
         // positions       // colors         // texture coords
         0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, // top right
         0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, // bottom right
        -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, // bottom left
        -1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, // top left 
    };
    unsigned int indices[] = {
        0, 1, 3, // first triangle
        1, 2, 3  // second triangle
    };
    unsigned int VBO, VAO, EBO;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &EBO);

    glBindVertexArray(VAO);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    // position attribute
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    // color attribute
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(float), (void*)(3 * sizeof(float)));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    // texture coord attribute
    glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(float), (void*)(6 * sizeof(float)));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);

    // load and create a texture 
    // -------------------------
    GL2D_Texture* texture = GL2D_CreateTextureFromFile("assets/i.jpg");

    // render loop
    // -----------
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        // input
        // -----
        processInput(window);

        // render
        // ------
        glClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        // bind Texture
        GL2D_BindTexture(texture);

        // render container
        glUseProgram(shaderProgram);
        glBindVertexArray(VAO);
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);

        // glfw: swap buffers and poll IO events (keys pressed/released, mouse moved etc.)
        // -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    // optional: de-allocate all resources once they've outlived their purpose:
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &VBO);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &EBO);

    // glfw: terminate, clearing all previously allocated GLFW resources.
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------
    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}

// process all input: query GLFW whether relevant keys are pressed/released this frame and react accordingly
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void processInput(GLFWwindow* window)
{
    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE) == GLFW_PRESS)
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, 1);
}

// glfw: whenever the window size changed (by OS or user resize) this callback function executes
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void framebuffer_size_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height)
{
    // make sure the viewport matches the new window dimensions; note that width and 
    // height will be significantly larger than specified on retina displays.
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
}
```

GL2D.h

```
#ifdef GL2D_USE_DLL
    #define GL2D_API __declspec(dllimport)
#else
    #define GL2D_API
#endif

#include <stdint.h>

typedef struct GL2D_Vector2F {
    float x;
    float y;
} GL2D_Vector2F;

typedef struct GL2D_Texture GL2D_Texture;
GL2D_API GL2D_Texture* GL2D_CreateTextureFromFile(const char* path);
GL2D_API void GL2D_BindTexture(GL2D_Texture* texture);
```

GL2D.c

```
#ifdef GL2D_DLL_BUILD
    #define GL2D_USE_DLL
#endif

#include "gl2d.h"

#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <memory.h>
#include <glad/glad.h>
#define STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION
#include <stb/stb_image.h>

#undef GL2D_API
#ifdef GL2D_DLL_BUILD 
    #define GL2D_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
    #define GL2D_API
#endif

struct GL2D_Texture {
    uint32_t id;
    uint8_t slot;
    GL2D_Vector2F size;
};

GL2D_API GL2D_Texture* GL2D_CreateTextureFromFile(const char* path) {
    GL2D_Texture* texture = malloc(sizeof(GL2D_Texture));

    if (texture == NULL) {
        printf("Error: couldn't allocate texture");
        return NULL;
    }

    memset(texture, 0, sizeof(GL2D_Texture));

    glGenTextures(1, &texture->id);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture->id); // all upcoming GL_TEXTURE_2D operations now have effect on this texture object
    // set the texture wrapping parameters
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);   // set texture wrapping to GL_REPEAT (default wrapping method)
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
    // set texture filtering parameters
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    // load image, create texture and generate mipmaps
    int width = 0, height = 0, nrChannels = 0;
    // The FileSystem::getPath(...) is part of the GitHub repository so we can find files on any IDE/platform; replace it with your own image path.
    stbi_set_flip_vertically_on_load(1);
    unsigned char* data = stbi_load("assets/i.jpg", &width, &height, &nrChannels, 0);
    if (data) {
        if (nrChannels == 3) {
            glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
            glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        }
        else if (nrChannels == 4) {
            glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
            glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        }
        else {
            printf("Failed to load texture\n");
        }
    }
    else {
        printf("Failed to load texture\n");
    }
    stbi_image_free(data);

    texture->size.x = width;
    texture->size.y = height;

    return texture;
}

GL2D_API void GL2D_BindTexture(GL2D_Texture* texture) {
    glActiveTexture(texture->slot);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture->id);
}
```

GL2D.c is compiled to library using cl compiler and Main.c link to it